# java settings via registry in windows client

Tags: registry, java

Does anyone know how to set the JRE values from the below dialog via a registry key ?
nothing obvious in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment
(or where the heck these values are stored ?)

We have to set the command line memory allocation for our users and they have difficulty typing the arguments, hitting return and the clicking OK.

I was figuring just create a SetCmdArgs.rgs file and have them use regedit to set the values.

from "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javacpl.exe" on XP
from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\javacpl.exe" on Win7
[image]

Thanks,
Craig

Answer (score 14):

It seems to be the file
`C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties` where the command line arguments are stored.

Adding `test123` in the command line arguments changes the file to the following:

```
deployment.javaws.jre.1.location=http\://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se
deployment.javaws.jre.1.args=test123
deployment.javaws.jre.1.enabled=true
deployment.javaws.jre.1.registered=true
deployment.javaws.jre.1.product=1.6.0_22
deployment.javaws.jre.1.path=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre6\\bin\\javaw.exe
deployment.javaws.jre.1.osarch=amd64
deployment.javaws.jre.1.osname=Windows
deployment.javaws.jre.1.platform=1.6
```

At least, I can manually edit the file and the changes show up in the Java Control Panel.
The file's documentation can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/properties.html).