# Where does Java preferences API store the values under Windows?

Tags: javafx, preferences

After saving some application preferences via java.util.prefs API, I cannot find them.
This is a Windows 7 machine and I searched registry for the path `JavaFXApp1` and individual values I've saved such as `CurrentColor`, but found nothing.

The values have been saved for certain, as the application reads them when it starts.

Where does Java preferences API store the values under Windows? This is my saving and reading code:

```
Preferences prf = Preferences.userRoot().node("/JavaFXApp1");
prf.putInt("CurrentColor", appCtrl.getIValue());

Preferences prf = Preferences.userRoot().node("/JavaFXApp1");
i = prf.getInt("CurrentColor", 0);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are the Java preferences stored in Windows 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947555/where-are-the-java-preferences-stored-in-windows-7)

Comment: And for God's sake, why was the key name changed to `/Java/F/X/App1`??? No wonder I could not find it. It butchered the value names in the similar manner: `/Current/Color` etc. It even added a forward slash in front of one text value's text: `/Programmatically set text`. Unless this has a rock solid justification, this would make configuration management a nightmare.

Comment: Just don't use camelCase rather go for current-color type of case (forgot what exactly its called).

Comment: Take a look at this: [In Java, why does WindowsPreferences use slashes for capital letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23001152/4071001)