# Java Preferences: slashes in value names

Tags: java

Why is Java's Preferences API putting slashes before capital letters in value names? **Is there any way to get around this or disable this behavior?**

[image]

```
prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node("app");
...
prefs.putInt("WindowWidth", mainFrame.getWidth());
...
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, why does WindowsPreferences use slashes for capital letters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001152/in-java-why-does-windowspreferences-use-slashes-for-capital-letters)

Comment: I'm sorry. Is there any way to prevent this from hapenning?

Comment: Have a look at it:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java/11854901#11854901