# Accessing HKEY_CURRENT_USER via Preferences in Java

Tags: java, registry, preferences

I am trying to write a registry key in the following path in the registry:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> Software -> TestApp

I am currently doing:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Preferences p = Preferences.userRoot().node("/HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/TestApp");
    p.put("TestKey", "TestValue");
}
```

But it writes it at HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> Software -> JavaSoft -> Prefs -> /H/K/E/Y_/C/U/R/R/E/N/T/_/U/S/E/R -> Software -> Test/App

How do I get it to follow the absolute path, and why is it putting extra slashes in?

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look to this beautiful blog post about [Read/Write the registry](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0630.html)

I may draw your attention to this passage of the code:

> ```
> /**
>    * Write a value in a given key/value name
>    * @param hkey
>    * @param key
>    * @param valueName
>    * @param value
>    * @throws IllegalArgumentException
>    * @throws IllegalAccessException
>    * @throws InvocationTargetException
>    */
>   public static void writeStringValue
>     (int hkey, String key, String valueName, String value)
>     throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
>     InvocationTargetException
>   {
>     if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
>       writeStringValue(systemRoot, hkey, key, valueName, value);
>     }
>     else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
>       writeStringValue(userRoot, hkey, key, valueName, value);
>     }
>     else {
>       throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
>     }
>   }
> ```

I think this solution is very elegant in onder to manage read/write operations against the registry.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get it to follow the absolute path

You can use reflection to access the private methods in the java.util.prefs.Preferences class. See this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6163701/6256127

However, I don't recommend using this approach as it may break at any time.

> why is it putting extra slashes in?

Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23632932/6256127

> Registry-Keys are case-preserving, but case-insensitive. For example if you have a key "Rbi" you cant make another key named "RBi". The case is saved but ignored. Sun's solution for case-sensitivity was to add slashes to the key.