# How to find where a jar is storing information

Tags: java, jar, output, file-location

I do not have access to the source code but I have a jar file that takes some input for settings when it is run.  It remembers the settings for subsequent runs so I assumed that it was storing information internally. However, if I delete the jar and download a new copy, the *new copy has access to the same information the deleted one had*.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe this means it is storing/reading a file somewhere on my system? Is there any way to find that file? I tried hoping on windows and searching all files by date modified, but no such luck.  Can hop on Ubuntu if needed.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: check the usual temporary folders, they might be stored in those

Comment: tried c:\temp nothing there

Comment: Check your user home directory; a lot of applications will create an app-specific folder there to store information (the folder may be hidden). Or check the standard location for application data used by your operating system (e.g. `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\...` on Windows—not sure about MacOS or Linux).

Comment: I've been poking around in C:\Users\<user>\AppData\ for a while.  Can't seem to find it :(

Comment: not too concerned about this windows installation, might start blowing away folders and see what happens

Comment: What kind of jar file is it? Free for everyone available on the internet? If so can you share a link? is there a doku / readme? Or is it provided to you by the programmer? If so why don't you ask him?

Comment: @Eritrean no dice on documentation unfortunately.  Although It's public, it's from a school and probably best not to link here. When I noticed it had to be reading/writing local data I just got curious to see if I could find what it was doing.

Comment: I've also tried revoking read/write priviledges to see if I can get a directory to pop up but no such luck there either

Comment: found it on linux, in a hidden java folder in home directory.  still looking on windows for the equivalent

Comment: The application may be using the [Preferences API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.prefs/module-summary.html), in which case I believe that API stores preferences in the registry on Windows.

Comment: @Slaw thanks I didn't know about that. Will check it out.

Comment: @Slaw sorry for the delayed follow up, turns out you were right.  found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947555/where-are-the-java-preferences-stored-in-windows-7 based on what you said, thanks again